# Unity2D - Verify if isGround is correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a script that detect when player is touching a layer named "Ground", and it works pretty well, but my problem is when I use the "Platform Effector 2D" that allows me jump through the plataform. So, when my character is passsing through the plataform, my bool "isGrounded" gets true, but he is actually not in ground, what happens is that the point that I use to check is "colliding" with the object that countains the layer Ground.

I don't think I can explain it very well, so I upload a not listed video on Youtube to show

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQpF4iSNC0Yt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQpF4iSNC0Yt)

here's the code

```
[Header("Components")]
[HideInInspector]public Rigidbody2D _rb;

[Header("Layer Masks")]
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

[Header("Movement Variables")]
[SerializeField] private float _movementAcceleration;
[SerializeField] private float _maxMoveSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float _linearDrag;
[SerializeField] private float dashPower;
private float horizontalDirection;
private bool changingDirection => (_rb.velocity.x > 0f &&  horizontalDirection < 0f) || (_rb.velocity.x < 0f && horizontalDirection > 0f);
public bool isFalling => _rb.velocity.y < 0.0f;
private bool isRunning => horizontalDirection != 0;

[Header("Jump Variables")]
[SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 12f;
[SerializeField] private float airLinearDrag = 2.5f;
[SerializeField] private float fallMultiplier = 8f;
[SerializeField] private float lowJumpFallMultiplier = 5f;
private bool canJump => Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGround;
[Header("Ground Colission Variables")]
[SerializeField] private float groundRayCastLenght;

private bool isGround;
private bool jumped;    
private bool facinRight = true;
private Animator animator;
private SpriteRenderer sprite;
GameController controller;
public Transform    groundCheck         ;
public bool canPassThrough = false;

void Start()
{
    
    sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    controller = FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(_rb.velocity.y);
    isGround = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

    horizontalDirection = GetInput().x;
    if(canJump && !controller.gamePaused){      
        Jump();
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
        ApplyDash();
    }
    
    setAnimations();
    
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //CheckCollisions();
    if(!controller.gamePaused){
        //checkDirection();
        MoveCharacter();    
    }
    if(isGround){
        jumped = false;
        ApplyLinearDrag();
    }else{
        ApplyAirLinearDrag();
        FallMultiplier();
    }        
    
}

private Vector2 GetInput()
{
    
    return new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
}
private void MoveCharacter(){
    if(horizontalDirection < 0 && facinRight || horizontalDirection > 0 && !facinRight){
        checkDirection();
    }
    Vector3 v = _rb.velocity;
    _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalDirection* _movementAcceleration, 0f) );
    if(Mathf.Abs(_rb.velocity.x) > _maxMoveSpeed){
        v.x = Mathf.Sign(_rb.velocity.x) * _maxMoveSpeed;
        _rb.velocity = v;
        //_rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(_rb.velocity.x) * _maxMoveSpeed, _rb.velocity.y );
    }
    
        
}
private void CheckCollisions(){
    isGround = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position * groundRayCastLenght, Vector2.down, groundRayCastLenght, groundLayer);
}
private void ApplyLinearDrag(){
    if(Mathf.Abs(horizontalDirection) < 0.4f || changingDirection){
        _rb.drag = _linearDrag;
    }else{
        _rb.drag = 0f;
    }
}
private void ApplyDash(){
    _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalDirection * dashPower, _rb.velocity.y));
}
void ApplyAirLinearDrag(){
    _rb.drag = airLinearDrag;
}
void Jump(){
    jumped = true;
    if(horizontalDirection != 0){
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        _rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);        
    }else{
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        _rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * 2f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    
}    
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.down * groundRayCastLenght);
}
void FallMultiplier(){
    
    if(_rb.velocity.y < 0){
        _rb.gravityScale = fallMultiplier;
    }else if(_rb.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")){
        _rb.gravityScale = lowJumpFallMultiplier;
    }else{
        _rb.gravityScale = 1f;
    }
}
void setAnimations(){
    animator.SetBool("Run", isRunning && isGround);
    animator.SetBool("isGround", isGround);
    animator.SetBool("Jump", jumped);
    animator.SetBool("isFalling", isFalling);   
    animator.SetFloat("eixoY", Mathf.Abs(_rb.velocity.y));
}
void checkDirection(){
    facinRight = !facinRight;
    transform.localScale = new  Vector3( - transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(LayerMask.LayerToName(other.gameObject.layer) == "Ground") //check layer is ground
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y <= 0) //check velocity.y is 0
        {
            Debug.Log("in ground"); //debug console
            canPassThrough = false;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Not in ground");
            canPassThrough = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about you also add to your condition a reliance on an indication that would only be true when the character is in jumping state? Because actually he is touching the ground but since you want to allow the user to jump through a platform then clearly there's a case that needs some more attention. Also, could you provide the minimal amount of code and scene setup details in the question so we can further assist.

Comment: I posted the player code

Comment: How can I add other condicion to player jumping? 'Cause I set false when player is on the ground, but when player is passing through the plataform, the variable isground detect that he is on ground,  when actually he is not

Comment: I think you would benefit from learning about states and state machines. Don't need a big state machine encompassing everything, Breaking down the state machine into relevant components where it matters will help. So many results out there. [Mit](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/unit-1-software-engineering/state-machines/MIT6_01SCS11_chap04.pdf) has a bit of a verbose one if you are interested. But there might be other simpler ones you can find.

Comment: Relying on too many `bool`s is likely to lead to many edge cases and bugs and (much more than needed) code branches. If you have any difficulty after reading about state machine or just don't know how to apply it lmk and I can explain further.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to perform the debug operation when we touch it, we can perform the operation successfully by checking that the velocity.y is 0 at the moment it touches.

like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(LayerMask.LayerToName(collision.gameObject.layer) == "Ground") //check layer is ground
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y <= 0) //check velocity.y is 0
        {
            Debug.Log("in ground"); //debug console
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to do it, but my velocity.y is king of weird, it returns me something like 2 when running, i'm trying to fix this

Comment: Actually it works, but when I  jump and  the  player  is colliding with the plataform, but is not in  ground, if I jump and keep walking to side, gets me error, 'cause  te velocity of the  player goes from -7 to 7, and  de condicion ".velocity.y <= 0" returns that the player is in ground when he isn't